# Scala Type Mismatch with Nested function call

Tags: scala, types

I have this code that I can't seem to get to work. The code is supposed to allow you to determine if the bounding boxes of a circle and rectangle overlap each other.

```
    abstract class Shape
    case class Circle(r: Double, x: Double, y: Double) extends Shape
    case class Rectangle(llx: Double, lly: Double, w:Double, h:Double) extends Shape


 def boundingBox(s: Shape): Rectangle = s match {
      case Rectangle(llx, lly, w, h) => Rectangle(llx, lly, w, h)
      case Circle(r,x,y) => Rectangle(x-r, y-r, 2*r, 2*r)
    }


    def mayOverlap(s1: Shape, s2: Shape) = overlapRect(boundingBox(s1), boundingBox(s2))

    def overlapRect(r1: Rectangle, r2: Rectangle) = betweenLine(r1.llx, r1.w, r2.llx, r2.w) && betweenLine(r1.lly, r1.h, r2.lly, r2.h)

    def betweenLine(x: Double, l: Double, a: Double, k: Double): Boolean = (a <= x+l) || (a+l <= x+l)
```

All the function are operating correctly except for mayOverlap. When I load these functions into the interpreter, I get back the following error:

```
<console>:63: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Rectangle(in object $iw)
 required: Rectangle(in object $iw)
       def mayOverlap(s1: Shape, s2: Shape) = overlapRect(boundingBox(s1), boundingBox(s2))
                                                                     ^
<console>:63: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Rectangle(in object $iw)
 required: Rectangle(in object $iw)
       def mayOverlap(s1: Shape, s2: Shape) = overlapRect(boundingBox(s1), boundingBox(s2))
```

I'm very new to scala, I'm much more familiar with haskell so it's possible I'm making assumptions of similarity between the two but I've tried to simplify it down and I can't seem to make any nested function calls in mayOverlap at all.

Comment: Which Scala version are you using? I can't reproduce this in the REPL.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by reordering the function declarations so the nested helper functions came first.